# Post Miller, have there been any obscenity convictions or prohibitions for purely textual material?

Tags: first-amendment

If I understand correctly, a U.S. state could in principle criminalize or otherwise prevent publication of a text-only book meeting the [three-pronged test for obscenity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_test) handed down in *Miller v. California*. Before that case, there were several important obscenity trials involving literary works, including *Ulysses* and *The Naked Lunch*. Since then, it has seemed as if the *Miller* test has been treated as having a tacit corollary that text-only works are never obscene. But is that impression wrong? Have any *successful* enforcement actions been brought against text-only content? (Recently, an attempt was made to restrict sales of two books in Virginia, but [that was dismissed](https://www.virginiamercury.com/2022/08/30/judge-throws-out-obscenity-case-attempting-to-restrict-sales-of-books-in-virginia-beach/).)

Comment: I know of at least one, but that involved a plea bargain rather than a conviction in an adversarial trial subject to appeal. It was related to a translated Japanese short novel relating child molestation, somewhere in the Western U.S.

Comment: Why not make this an answer?

Comment: @MarkFoksey Because I can't find a link or citation to support my vague recollection from some time ago.

Comment: My recall wasn't perfect but the case I was thinking about was this one. https://www.wired.com/2010/02/obscene-us-manga-collector-jailed-6-months/ See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Handley and https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=1511687855848739506&q=635+F.3d+1200+(2011)&hl=en&as_sdt=20000006&as_vis=1#%5B6%5D None of them was purely textual material.

Answer (score 2):

An almost-successful case is the recent case [Pennsylvania v. Alexander](https://www.pacourts.us/assets/opinions/Superior/out/J-S17041-21o%20-%20104819877139092537.pdf?cb=1), where the defendant was convicted of sending obscene text messages. However, the conviction was overturned on appeal to the PA Superior Court. The trial court, as summarized in the appeal

> reasoned that text messages may constitute obscene “material” because
> the statutory definition does not “expressly exclude” them, and the
> General Assembly must have intended for them to fall within the ambit
> of the obscenity statute.

and

> because the messages appealed to the prurient interest, described
> patently offensive sexual conduct, and lacked any social value,
> Alexander’s messages were “obscene” as defined in Section 5903(b)

Defendant argues (and the appeals court agrees) that

> the statute does not make it a crime to send sexually explicit text
> messages to a consenting adult

because the law

> only criminalizes the dissemination of obscene “material”: No person,
> knowing the obscene character of the **materials** or performances
> involved, shall: . . . . design, copy, draw, photograph, print, utter,
> publish or in any manner manufacture or prepare any obscene **materials**

(emphasis in appellate ruling)

and 18 Pa.C.S. § 5903(a)(3)(i) states that

> Obscene “material” is defined for the purposes of that subsection as:
> Any literature, including any book, magazine, pamphlet, newspaper,
> storypaper, bumper sticker, comic book or writing; any figure, visual
> representation, or image, including any drawing, photograph, picture,
> videotape or motion picture.

The conviction was overturned because the texts were not "material": as the appellate court reasoned,

> even assuming that Alexander’s texts were obscene under the Miller
> test, private and consensual text messages between two adults are not
> “material” within the meaning of subsection 5903(b). For the purposes
> of the statute, “obscene material” unambiguously refers to content
> made for public dissemination.

This "necessarily excludes private speech
exchanged via text messages by two consenting adults". The ruling does not consider whether a message disseminated to three or four adults would constitute "public dissemination".

Comment: Whether a group is the public has nothing to do with its size. For example, members of the US Armed Forces are a very numerous group but they are not “the public”. Conversely, display in a very small space to which only half a dozen people can fit might be public display if anyone is free to access it.